# Animated react routes not working with <Switch> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

I am trying to build a simple router for my React application, which would consist of a few routes generated from an array of objects and a static 404 route. The requirement is that transitions between every route must be animated.

I am using `react-router` for the browser and `react-transition-group`.

I want to achieve something like this (stripped-down, incomplete pseudo-code):

```
const routes = [
    { path: "/", component: Home },
    { path: "/about", component: About },
    { path: "/contact", component: Contact }
];

const createRoute = (route) => {
    return (
        <CSSTransition className="page" timeout={300}>
            <Route path={route.path} exact component={route.component} />
        </CSSTransition>
    );
}

<Router>
    {routes.map(createRoute)}
    <CSSTransition className="page" timeout={300}>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
    </CSSTransition>
</Router>
```

A full version of this code can be found on this Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-switch-csstransition-catch-all-route-bug-forked-qzt9g

I need to use the `<Switch>` component to prevent the 404 route from showing in all the other routes of the application, but as soon as I add the `<Switch>`, the animations stop working.

In the example above, you will see that the animations don't work when used with `<Switch>`, despite following the guides from official docs of both `react-router` and `react-transition-group`.

However, they work perfectly without the use of the `<Switch>`, but then of course I end up with 404 route showing all the time.

Expected result:

- animated transitions between all routes, those dynamically created as well as the static 404 page

Actual result:

- no animations at all or animations with 404 route always showing

I have spent the entire day trying to find a solution to the problem that I encountered. Unfortunately I can't seem to find anything that would remotely help me fix the issue I'm facing, and I've searched on Google, Stack Overflow, Medium and finally I'm back here hoping someone can help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the animation working with the Switch component, you have to pass the right **location** with **withRouter** to the **CSSTransition**, coupled with **TransitionGroup** component.
I've modified you sandbox code with the following working solution:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const components = {
  Home: () => <div>Home page</div>,
  About: () => <div>About the company</div>,
  Contact: () => <div>Contact us</div>,
  NotFound: () => <div>404</div>,
  Menu: ({ links, setIsSwitch }) => (
    <div className="menu">
      {links.map(({ path, component }, key) => (
        <Link key={key} to={path}>
          {component}
        </Link>
      ))}
      <Link to="/404">404</Link>
    </div>
  )
};

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: "Home" },
  { path: "/about", component: "About" },
  { path: "/contact", component: "Contact" }
];

const createRoutes = (routes) =>
  routes.map(({ component, path }) => {
    const Component = components[component];
    const nodeRef = React.createRef();

    return (
      <Route key={path} path={path} exact>
        {({ match }) => {
          return (
            <div ref={nodeRef} className="page">
              <Component />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Route>
    );
  });

const AnimatedSwitch = withRouter(({ location }) => (
  <TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition
      key={location.key}
      timeout={500}
      classNames="page"
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <Switch location={location}>{createRoutes(routes)}</Switch>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <components.Menu links={routes} />
      <AnimatedSwitch />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

This article explains in detail the reasoning behind it: https://latteandcode.medium.com/react-how-to-animate-transitions-between-react-router-routes-7f9cb7f5636a.

By the way **withRouter** is deprecated in react-router **v6**.
So you should implement that hook in your own.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    
    return (
      <Component
        history={history}
        {...props}
        />
    );
  };
  
  return Wrapper;
};
```

See Deprecated issue discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7156.

Comment: Thank you @lamazing, it works! The bounty's yours :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is you can do following

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={"/:page(|about|contact)"}
    render={() => createRoutes(routes)}
  />
  <Route>
    <div className="page">
      <components.NotFound />
    </div>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Obviously not the most elegant nor scalable solution. But doable for a small react site.

Here's the forked codesandbox of working code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-switch-csstransition-catch-all-route-bug-forked-dhv39

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I was checking `router.location.key` first, but reaching through address bar was causing 404 page to render every page, so this is safer.

You can pass router as props to pages and conditionally render 404 page by checking `router.location.pathname`

```
export const routes = [
...all of your routes,
{
    path: "*",
    Component: NotFound,
  },
]


    {routes.map(({ path, pageTitle, Component }) => (
        <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
          {router => (
            <CSSTransition
              in={router.match !== null}
              timeout={400}
              classNames="page"
              unmountOnExit
            >
              <div className="page">
                <Component router={router} />
              </div>
            </CSSTransition>
          )}
        </Route>
      ))}
```

And in your 404 component, you need to check the path of the current route if it is available around all routes:

```
import { routes } from "../Routes";

const checkIfRouteIsValid = path => routes.findIndex(route => route.path === path);

export default function NotFound(props) {
  const pathname = props.router.location.pathname;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
   setShow(checkIfRouteIsValid(pathname) === -1);
  }, [pathname]);
    return (
      show && (
        <div>Not found!</div>
       )
     );
   }
```